# NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, spring, jetty, drools, janino

I have found similar problems on the web, but none of the posted solutions appear to work.

I am attempting to run my web application under jetty instead of always building and running in tomcat to test because our build takes 18 minutes. :(

This is a drools project and I am running under Eclipse Indigo SR2. I am trying to run under Jetty 6.1.26 and Spring Framework 2.5.6.

I have created the debug configuration with the following system parms in the vm args section in https://community.jboss.org/wiki/RulesTomcat:

-Djava.naming.factory.initial=org.mortbay.naming.InitialContextFactory -Ddrools.compiler=JANINO

Here is one of the many similar errors I'm getting:

```
2012-06-15 09:19:16.579:WARN::Nested in org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'strategyFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/conf/spring/beans.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'court' while setting bean property 'court'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'court' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/conf/spring/beans.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'instanceConfig' while setting bean property 'config'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'instanceConfig' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/conf/spring/beans.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'workflowManager' while setting bean property 'workflowMgr'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'workflowManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/conf/spring/workflow.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.CompilationResult.getProblems()[Lorg/eclipse/jdt/core/compiler/CategorizedProblem;:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.CompilationResult.getProblems()[Lorg/eclipse/jdt/core/compiler/CategorizedProblem;
    at org.drools.commons.jci.compilers.EclipseJavaCompiler$3.acceptResult(EclipseJavaCompiler.java:321)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:335)
    at org.drools.commons.jci.compilers.EclipseJavaCompiler.compile(EclipseJavaCompiler.java:351)
    at org.drools.commons.jci.compilers.AbstractJavaCompiler.compile(AbstractJavaCompiler.java:51)
    at org.drools.rule.builder.dialect.java.JavaDialect.compileAll(JavaDialect.java:389)
    at org.drools.compiler.DialectCompiletimeRegistry.compileAll(DialectCompiletimeRegistry.java:56)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageRegistry.compileAll(PackageRegistry.java:74)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.compileAll(PackageBuilder.java:677)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.addPackage(PackageBuilder.java:640)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.addPackageFromDrl(PackageBuilder.java:254)
    at com.acs.gs.io.DroolsUtil.getRuleBaseFromDrl(DroolsUtil.java:116)
    at com.acs.gs.io.DroolsUtil.getRuleBaseFromSpreadSheet(DroolsUtil.java:104)
    at com.acs.gs.io.DroolsUtil.getRuleBase(DroolsUtil.java:89)
    at com.acs.gs.juror.workflow.RulesBasedWorkflowManager.init(RulesBasedWorkflowManager.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1412)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1373)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:471)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:220)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:269)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:104)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1244)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1008)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:470)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:220)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:269)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:104)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1244)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1008)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:470)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:220)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:269)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:104)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1244)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1008)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:470)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:220)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:429)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:729)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:381)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:549)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1282)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:518)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:499)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at runjettyrun.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:97)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you are using an incompatible combination of libraries.

The class org.drools.commons.jci.compilers.EclipseJavaCompiler is trying to use `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.CompilationResult.getProblems()[Lorg/eclipse/jdt/core/compiler/CategorizedProblem` but that method doesn't exist in the Eclsipe library you are using.

Comment: Uh, OK. I'll buy that. So, pretend like I don't know what to do about this.

Comment: Replace the JAR with a version that has the updated class and try again.

Comment: You need to find the combination of libraries which are supposed to go together. The only way to determine this is to read the documentation for those libraries, most likely `drools` was built for an older version of `eclipse` at a guess so I would start with the drools docs.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I got the error as NoSuchMethodError:  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook.close()V

After removing the apache poi jar, the issue got resolved.